# Run play book with multiple conditions

Tags: ansible

I have written a  playbook which run handlers if the task was successful.Now I want to use some type conditions that if the above task fail then run different handler. Just like simple IF else statement works.

Current PLAYBOOK

```
  tasks:  
    - name: checking file format
      command: named-checkzone example.com /var/named/example.com
      notify: service


  handlers:
    - name: "service reload"
      command: rndc reload example.com
      listen: "service"
```

Now I want to omit file name in configuration file if the main tasks fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"1) Run handler if the task was successful. 2) If the task fails then run another handler."*

A: The simple way is to notify a handler when a task is *changed*. When a task fails the status is *failed* not *changed* and no handler is notified.

In this particular case, you don't care whether the command succeeded or failed. The handler shall always be notified. This can be achieved by an explicit combination of `ignore_errors, failed_when, and changed_when`.

Notify both handlers `service success` and `service fail`. The conditions in the handlers will decide which handler will run. For example the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - command: "{{ cmd }}"
      register: named_checkzone_result
      ignore_errors: true
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: true
      notify:
        - service success
        - service fail

  handlers:
    - name: service success
      debug:
        msg: Service success
      when: named_checkzone_result.rc == 0
    - name: service fail
      debug:
        msg: Service fail
      when: named_checkzone_result.rc == 1
```

gives (abridged) if the command succeeds

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "cmd=true"

TASK [command] ****
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [service success] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Service success

RUNNING HANDLER [service fail] ****
skipping: [localhost]
```

gives (abridged) if the command fails

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "cmd=false"

TASK [command] ****
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [service success] ****
skipping: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [service fail] ****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Service fail
```